# Losing My Mind With Like Funcitonality

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

We have 3 environments that we have setup Facebook like functionality on. We have run the linter, debug, on the URLs for all three environments and they all display correctly through the tool however the real production site does not display correctly when an end-user hits the like button.

Three Example URLs:
stage.mobile.wilmasrecipes.com/iphone/shareRecipes.aspx?RecipeID=FULLSITE
review.mobile.wilmasrecipes.com/iphone/shareRecipes.aspx?RecipeID=FULLSITE
mobile.wilmasrecipes.com/iphone/shareRecipes.aspx?RecipeID=FULLSITE

Translate respectively to:
    *_*_https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstage.mobile.wilmasrecipes.com%2FDefault.aspx (No image)
   https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Freview.mobile.wilmasrecipes.com%2FDefault.aspx (Displays Correctly)
   https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmobile.wilmasrecipes.com%2FDefault.aspx (Displays Completely Different Text/URL/Image)

We have spent two days searching forums, and working through the linter tool but no matter what we do, the production site does not function the same as stage or review. I realize I am a newbie to this, but I have checked and rechecked that the code in each environment is the same.

I have seen some similar posts, but there never appears to be a clear answer. Anyone out there have suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that facebook is inadvertently caching an older version of the Default.aspx page.  Could you, for testing purposes, create something like Default2.aspx and point the og:url to that from shareRecipes.aspx?  If that is so, then this may be your fix.  Try changing to using Index.aspx for the default page and hopefully Facebook will pick up the correct items.

Answer (score 0):

You are image is this,

```
http://stage.mobile.wilmasrecipes.com/images/facebook_WilmasLandingImage.png
```

Try to call image from other domain or sub domain , I was facing same problem.But it worked later , and fb do cache, you you may have to wait for result.